# How to specify the register size (b/w/d) in a macro

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, cpu-registers

I would like to learn a way of specifying the size of a general-register argument.

for instance:

```
%macro lalala 1
  mov word [buff], %1w
%endmacro
```

it works only for `r8`-`r15`, but I would like to use this macro for them all `rax`-`rdx`,`rdi`,`rsi`,`r8`-`r15`.

How should I go about it? Is there a built-in mapping?

Comment: Why not pass the correct register name in the first place, like `ax`?  Does your actual use-case involve using multiple sizes of the same register, like `movzx %k1, byte [mem]` / `mov [dst], %b1`.  (That `%k1` is GNU C inline asm operand-size override syntax for the 32-bit name of a register, not NASM.  IDK if NASM has anything equivalent.)  Anyway, I'd recommend updating your example to one that can't be trivially solved by having the caller pass the right name in the first place.

Comment: IDK if NASM's macro string processing is powerful enough for this, but a `%if` might be possible to append a `w` if it ends with a digit, otherwise keep the last 2 characters (or strip the leading character).

Comment: @Peter Cordes: It can be done, as a last resort, using `%defstr`, `%strlen`, `%substr`, and a bunch of `%ifidni` / other `%if...` constructs, and finally `%deftok`. But there may be an easier way: Using the directive `%use altreg` ([documented here](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.1)) you can use numeric names for all registers.

Comment: @ecm: Interesting idea to use `altreg`, but that would only work if you require the caller to use `lalala r0` not `lalala rax`.  That's a high price to pay.  :/  Unless you mean combining that with and `%ifidn` if/else chain to translate RAX to R0, etc. first.

Comment: @PeterCordes: actually, yes, there is a case of making a choice of the operand size inside the macro, so it would be better off getting hold of such a way which would enable me to map a reg name into its shrinked version. Now, it seems to me that mapping full names into numeric names inside the macro and adding a letter then is the best (shortest) way. Am I right?

Comment: @PeterCordes: Now, I got your piece of advice regarding `inline-asm` in GNU C and I am inclined to express that I do appreciate it, though it'd be for a later use, since it is not a C project which I'm got into now. BTW, does it work in GNU ASM? I mean that `%k1` syntax in the `as` preprocessor.

Comment: @dronte7: No, GNU C inline asm [operand modifiers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86-Operand-Modifiers) are specific to `asm("... %k0" :"+r"(var) :: )` in C, *not* GAS macros.  It's not a preprocessor thing, it's GNU C's own asm template substitution thing.  I wasn't suggesting you could use anything like that in any assembly language, it just popped into my head as a thing where you can expand register operands different ways.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I did mean that using `altreg` you would **have to** use `r0` etc. The additional handling to allow `rax` with `altreg`-style output would be similar to the amount of work needed to just use the default register names throughout (both as input and output). So the latter is what I did in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put together two NASM preprocessor macros which combined allow you to take any register name (of any size) as input, along with a size, and convert that into the appropriate register name of the given size. The `altreg` register names that I mentioned ([documented in the NASM manual here](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.1)) are not used by these macros at all. Compatibility for inputting `r0` to `r7` could be added without much effort though. Here are the full macros:

```
    %imacro regindexdef 2.nolist
%push
 %define _%1 256
 %assign %$size 0
 %assign %$exit 0
 %rep 5
  %ifn %$exit
   %if %$size == 0
    %define %$regnames "ah  ch  dh  bh  "
   %elif %$size == 1
    %define %$regnames "al  cl  dl  bl  spl bpl sil dil r8b r9b r10br11br12br13br14br15b"
   %elif %$size == 2
    %define %$regnames "ax  cx  dx  bx  sp  bp  si  di  r8w r9w r10wr11wr12wr13wr14wr15w"
   %elif %$size == 4
    %define %$regnames "eax ecx edx ebx esp ebp esi edi r8d r9d r10dr11dr12dr13dr14dr15d"
   %elif %$size == 8
    %define %$regnames "rax rcx rdx rbx rsp rbp rsi rdi r8  r9  r10 r11 r12 r13 r14 r15 "
   %endif
   %assign %$index 0
   %rep 16
    %ifn %$exit
     %substr %$reg %$regnames %$index * 4 + 1, 4
     %deftok %$reg %$reg
     %ifnempty %$reg
      %ifidni %$reg, %2
       %assign _%1 %$index
       %assign %$exit 1
       %exitrep
      %endif
     %endif
    %endif
    %assign %$index %$index + 1
   %endrep
   %if %$exit
    %exitrep
   %endif
   %assign %$size !%$size + %$size * 2
  %endif
 %endrep
 %ifn %$exit
  %error Invalid register name: %2
 %endif
%pop
    %endmacro


    %imacro regsizedef 3.nolist
%push
 %define _%1 invalidregister
 %assign %$size 0
 %assign %$highbyte 0
 %ifidni %2, byte
  %assign %$size 1
 %elifidni %2, highbyte
  %assign %$size 1
  %assign %$highbyte 1
 %elifidni %2, word
  %assign %$size 2
 %elifidni %2, dword
  %assign %$size 4
 %elifidni %2, qword
  %assign %$size 8
 %else
  %assign %$size %2
 %endif
 %if %$size == 0
  %error Invalid register size: %2
 %else
  %ifnnum %3
   %error Invalid register number: %3
  %elif (%3) >= 16
   %error Invalid register number: %3
  %elif (%3) < 0
   %error Invalid register number: %3
  %else
   %if %$size == 1 && %$highbyte
    %define %$regnames "ah  ch  dh  bh  "
   %elif %$size == 1
    %define %$regnames "al  cl  dl  bl  spl bpl sil dil r8b r9b r10br11br12br13br14br15b"
   %elif %$size == 2
    %define %$regnames "ax  cx  dx  bx  sp  bp  si  di  r8w r9w r10wr11wr12wr13wr14wr15w"
   %elif %$size == 4
    %define %$regnames "eax ecx edx ebx esp ebp esi edi r8d r9d r10dr11dr12dr13dr14dr15d"
   %elif %$size == 8
    %define %$regnames "rax rcx rdx rbx rsp rbp rsi rdi r8  r9  r10 r11 r12 r13 r14 r15 "
   %else
    %define %$regnames ""
   %endif
   %substr %$reg %$regnames (%3) * 4 + 1, 4
   %deftok %$reg %$reg
   %ifempty %$reg
    %error Invalid register type selected
   %else
    %xdefine _%1 %$reg
   %endif
  %endif
 %endif
%pop
    %endmacro
```

Here are a few valid examples of using the macros:

```
    bits 64

regsizedef REG, 2, 0
    mov _REG, 1234h
    ; mov to ax
regsizedef REG, 4, 0
    mov _REG, 12345678h
    ; mov to eax
regsizedef REG, qword, 0
%warning REG=>>_REG<<
; rax
regsizedef REG, highbyte, 2
%warning REG=>>_REG<<
; dh

regindexdef INDEX, rdi
regsizedef REG, word, _INDEX
    mov _REG, 1234h
    ; mov to di

regindexdef INDEX, cx
regsizedef REG, qword, _INDEX
%warning REG=>>_REG<< INDEX=>>_INDEX<<
; reg rcx, index 1
```

I also uploaded a file including the macros, the valid test cases, and a few invalid test cases: https://ulukai.org/ecm/20201207.txt (needs lmacros from https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/lmacros/)

Here's how to use the macros with your example:

```
%macro lalala 1
regindexdef INDEX, %1
regsizedef REG, word, _INDEX
  mov word [buff], _REG
%endmacro
```