# GNU Assembler GAS check if macro paramater is register

Tags: assembly, macros, gnu, gnu-assembler

I want handle in case if macro argument (parameter) is a register.

I expect I have similiar code like this but I'm sure it doesn't work due to lack my knowledge of directive syntax.

```
.macro myMacro myParameter
  .if \myParamater == "register"
    //a block code in case if paramater is register
    mov rax, 1
  .else
    //a block code in case if paramater is not register (maybe immadiately value)
    mov rax, 2
  .endif
.endm
```

So based on that code I can use macro like this

```
myMacro rdi //rax will be 1 because parameter is a register
myMacro 2 //rax will be 2 because parameter is not a register (immadiately value)
```

EDIT:
So what is correct `.if` condition syntax to check if macro parameter is a register or not? Because I'm not sure in `.if` condition syntax.

Comment: I'm not aware of any method to do so.  Consider producting two variants of the macro, one for registers and one for immediates.

Comment: Can you use an assembler with a more powerful macro processor, like NASM which can do string compares?  (You do have to write out all the register names to check against, including all relevant widths.)  Oh actually, GAS can `.ifeqs` aka `.ifc string1, string2` - https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/If.html (@fuz).

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not sure if that helps you when e.g. a symbol with the same name as a register is defined.

Comment: @PeterCordes I ever use it for a year ago, but I have already read mostly GAS documentation. Yes I recognized I can check it with checking all registers name. I think it's not problem for me to write out and check all registers one by one because registers quantity only a little not as much as memory adresses. But if we know register opcode I think we can use inequality operation if register opcode between register is sequantially regularly?

Comment: @fuz: Oh right, I was thinking of AT&T syntax for x86 where register names are decorated like  `%rax` to make that ambiguity impossible.  If you're worried about an ARM ambiguity between needing to do something like `ldr r1, =r0` (with a `.equ` symbol value as a constant) vs. `mov r1, r0` register copy, frankly you should just not use such poorly-chosen symbol names in your hand-written asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes "like NASM which can do string compares? (You do have to write out all the register names to check against, including all relevant widths.)" Example of doing just that somewhat readably: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65180767/how-to-specify-the-register-size-b-w-d-in-a-macro/65187576#65187576

Comment: @PeterCordes That is in general not possible as new register names can be defined after you wrote your code.  This is also why you can optionally decorate registers with a dollar sign in NASM.

Comment: @fuz - But not new GPRs, which is what matters for a macro that would use them in a specific context, and thus needs a GPR or a constant.  I guess to be fair, AVX-512 did create new XMM and YMM registers that are valid with the same mnemonics.  Still, for a macro that "goes with" some code that uses it, the limitations are acceptable.

Comment: @PeterCordes It doesn't really matter what the new register is—you'll still get a syntax error if you detect it as such and try to use it.  ARM64 e.g. seems to add about a dozen new tokens for system registers with each release.

Comment: @fuz: Ok sure, so you'll have to update your macro if you start using those new register names as args to it.  Doesn't seem like a huge deal to me, especially when the failure mode is noisy and obvious.  You wouldn't want to publish a set of macros as a "library" for use with other code if you were using potentially-brittle stuff like that, but otherwise probably good enough for most uses.

Comment: In assemblers with more [powerful macrolanguage](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/index.htm#TYPEha)  the expression `%IF TYPE# %myParameter = 'R'` evaluates as *true* no matter if `myParameter` happens to be `AL`, `al`, `xmm31` or any other x86-64 register name.

Comment: @PeterCordes Again, the problem is that you don't know when you write your code whether an identifier will be a register name in a future version of the assembler or not, so it's not forward compatible.  You cannot avoid having identifiers collide with register names.

Comment: @fuz: Oh right, fair point.  But with most symbol names, collisions are rather unlikely. 
 As long as the failure mode is noisy, it's probably fine to just fix it if it becomes a problem at some point in the future, especially since most projects won't have a huge amount of inline asm.  It should just be a search/replace after picking a new name, assuming you fix it before adding new code which uses the new register name as a register.

Comment: @PeterCordes Once again, that assumes you actually can maintain the code in the future.  I prefer I don't have to do that.  It's a lot better of a design to just assume that you cannot ever tell apart registers from symbol names.

Comment: @fuz: Ok, good point again.  Yes, I'd agree with that.  The question suggested distinguishing registers from immediates, but only numeric literals would truly be a different kind of text, and that would require pattern matching. (So only useful if you can expand symbols to constants before macro text compare, which would make it unusable on `.equ` constants that are symbols.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You maybe want check another else (not only register) for example check if it's a memory that store floating point or not.

## First, you need define your own data type identifier.

You can set whatever number ID you want as long they are different each other.

```
// Define Identifier (ID) for your data type
.set REGISTER_TYPE_ID, 1
.set INTEGER_TYPE_ID, 2
.set FLOAT_TYPE_ID, 3
.set STRING_TYPE_ID, 4
.set FUNCTION_TYPE_ID, 5
```

## Second, define every possible registers name with prefix `TypeOf.` to the `REGISTER_TYPE_ID`.

And again you can change prefix to whatever you want as long consistent to the macro.

```
// Define TypeOf for every possible registers in x64 machine
.set TypeOf.rax, REGISTER_TYPE_ID
.set TypeOf.rbx, REGISTER_TYPE_ID
.set TypeOf.rcx, REGISTER_TYPE_ID
// and so on...
```

## Third, define your macro.

If you just want debug macro or assembler you don't have to use machine instruction like `mov rax, 1`, instead use `.print "put string here"`

```
.macro myMacro myParam
  .ifnotdef "TypeOf.\myParam"
    .print "This parameter type is an IMMEDIATELY value (constant)!"
  .elseif "TypeOf.\myParam" == REGISTER_TYPE_ID
    .print "This parameter type is a REGISTER!"
  .elseif "TypeOf.\myParam" == FLOAT_TYPE_ID
    .print "This parameter type is a FLOAT!"
  .else
    .print "Unknown type ID \myParam (elseif not implemented)"
  .endif
.endm
```

## Example Usage

In this case there are another type to check for example `float`.

```
// Define Identifier (ID) for your data type
.set REGISTER_TYPE_ID, 1
.set INTEGER_TYPE_ID, 2
.set FLOAT_TYPE_ID, 3
.set STRING_TYPE_ID, 4
.set FUNCTION_TYPE_ID, 5

// Define TypeOf for every possible registers in x64 machine
.set TypeOf.rax, REGISTER_TYPE_ID
.set TypeOf.rbx, REGISTER_TYPE_ID
.set TypeOf.rcx, REGISTER_TYPE_ID
// and so on...

.macro myMacro myParam
  .ifnotdef "TypeOf.\myParam"
    .print "This parameter type is an IMMEDIATELY value (constant)!"
  .elseif "TypeOf.\myParam" == REGISTER_TYPE_ID
    .print "This parameter type is a REGISTER!"
  .elseif "TypeOf.\myParam" == FLOAT_TYPE_ID
    .print "This parameter type is a FLOAT!"
  .else
    .print "Unknown type ID \myParam (elseif not implemeted)"
  .endif
.endm

.data
  myVar: 
    .set TypeOf.myVar, FLOAT_TYPE_ID
    .float 1234

.text 
.global _start

myFunc:
  .set TypeOf.myFunc, FUNCTION_TYPE_ID
  mov rax, 123
  ret

_start:
  myMacro 453 //"This parameter type is an IMMEDIATELY value (constant)!"
  myMacro rax //"This parameter type is a REGISTER!"
  myMacro myVar //"This parameter type is a FLOAT!"
  myMacro myFunc "Unknown type ID myFunc (elseif not implemeted)"

_exit:
  mov rax, 60 //linux sys_exit
  mov rdi, 0
  syscall
```

## OUTPUT:

```
wawan@LAPTOP-DJH6CVKH:~/asmi-fw$ as utama.s -o utama.o -msyntax=intel -mnaked-reg
This parameter type is an IMMEDIATELY value (constant)!
This parameter type is a REGISTER!
This parameter type is an FLOAT!
Unknown type ID myFunc (elseif not implemeted)
```

Comment: The term you're looking for is "immediate", not "immediately".  But yes, interesting idea to define symbols involving the strings you want to categorize, instead of a chain of `.ifc`.    It has all the problems fuz pointed out in comments of not being future-proof against new register names in new ISA extensions, though, and you need `%eax..r15d` as well as `ax..r15w` and `al..r15b` / `r8l..r15l`, including sil, dil, etc.  And `ah..dh`.

Comment: And it probably only works for lower-case register names, broken on `myMacro AH` even though `mov AH, 1` is a valid instruction.  (That's fine if your project's coding-style is to always use lower-case.)

Comment: Like high level programming for 
a software that need update, hardware is posibble deprecated or having new changes too. So I think it's a common thing for a programmer about adapting changes.